# How do I search for Wikipedia pages that have all the words in my set

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have two terms A and B (strings) and I want all Wikipedia pages that have both these terms A and B, with no constraint regarding the order in which they appear and any phrase query or anything like that. I just want all result pages to be containing both these terms.

What is the syntax of the MediaWiki query that I should be constructing for the srsearch parameter?

Should I use srsearch="A|B" or srsearch="A&B" or srsearch="A,B" or srsearch=A|B

From the results I am getting, I am unable to make this decision.

Any advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate them by space, no quotes.

```
srsearch=A B
```

Or, as a URL,

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=A+B
```

(`+` denotes a space in URLs.)

Comment: Thanks Juhana, do you know if there is a concept of a span query like Lucene in MediaWiki? I would like to constrain that my query words should be within a window of certain length.